# For what values of $n$ is this fraction irreducible

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Question: for what values of $n$ is $\frac{2n+3}{n+3}$ irreducible?

I attempted to find their GCD using Euclid's algorithm:

$2n+3=2(n+3)-3$

I know that, for the fraction to be irreducible, the GCD must equal 1, so I would suppose we have to find the values of $n$ such that it equals 1, but the remainder is -3, which has no $n$ term.

Comment: You have shown that $\gcd(2n+3,n+3) = \gcd(n+3,-3)$. Can you calculate this latter expression? The answer will depend on $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after your division we have that
$$\frac{2n+3}{n+3}=2-\frac{3}{n+3}$$
and the given fraction is irreducible iff $\frac{3}{n+3}$ is irreducible. Now note that the numerator of the new fraction is a prime number, which means that this ratio is an integer iff the denominator $n+3$ is equal to $\pm1$ or $\pm 3$. 
Can you take it from here?

Comment: So, we try $n=\pm1$ and $n=\pm3$: for $n=\pm3$ the ratio is an integer ($\frac{3}{6}$ or $\frac{3}{0}$), so the initial fraction is reducible - for $n=\pm1$ the ratio is not an integer ($\frac{3}{4}$ or $\frac{3}{2}$), so it is irreducible, correct?

Comment: No, you have to consider $n+3=\pm1 $ or  $n+3=\pm3$ that is the fraction is reducible when $n=-6,-4,-2,0$.

Comment: Oh, crud, you're right. So, this fraction is reducible when $n+3=\pm1$  or $n+3=\pm3$, so it's reducible when $n=-3\pm1$ or $n=-3\pm3$ - so it's irreducible for all other values of $n$.

Comment: @MarksPolakovs Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If $d$ is a common divisor of $2n+3$ and $n+3$, it is also a divisor of $1(n+3)-(2n+3)=3$.

So the only possible non-trivial common divisor of $2n+3$ and $n+3$ is $3$.
 can you proceed?